# Jsonp callback in internet explorer not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, jsonp

I am using JSONP to gather data from an API with AJAX. I have tested my code in firefox and chrome and it works perfectly in those browsers.

The link I use has the following format: 

www.placeholder.com/foo/?jsonp=dataCallback

However, when I'm trying to do the exact same thing in Internet explorer 11 I get an error saying: 
Object doesn't support property or method 'dataCallback'

I noticed that in firefox and chrome, the window will contain an object called "dataCallback" when I perform the request. In Internet Explorer 11 however, there is no such thing as "dataCallback" present in the window when I perform the request.

```
        $.support.cors = true;

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            contentType: "application/javascript",
            crossDomain: true,
            async: true,
            cache: true,
            // Work with the response
            complete: function (response) {
                var data = window["dataCallback"]();
                callback(self.parseData(data, scope, end), transport);
            }
        });
```

I this a known issue? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was. The code above works perfectly fine for internet explorer.

What went wrong is that I built an URL with username:password encapsulated in it. Apparantly, internet explorer does not support including username and password in the URL, which is why it failed.